# Windows Vista: Change settings from safe mode to normal mode

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, window

windows vista how to change from safe mode?

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Normally if the system is booting into Safe Mode it's because of an issue.  However, check the Boot tab in `msconfig` and ensure nothing is checked in the Boot options section.

Answer (score 0):

If you having booted into to [safe mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Start-your-computer-in-safe-mode), the only way to get back to normal is to restart the computer.

Comment: I tried that and still can't change to normal mode help!